# Docker - defining docker file to set up for deployment

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, deployment

I have a `dockerfile` which I used for building images locally.

I want to add configuration so it can be viewed directly on the specific port after the deployment.

So I suppose everythingg should be up and running and contain all the data needed, so the application can start.

I will share `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "./docker-configs/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - ".:/app:cached"
  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker-configs/php
    volumes:
      - "./docker-configs/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
      - ".:/app:cached"
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"

  database:
    image: mysql:8.1.0
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: project_db
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

And the `Dockerfile` that is not configured right as for now I am sure something is missing as it did not work.
This is the first time I am doing a deployment so if anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    wget \
    && apt-get install -y \
            librabbitmq-dev \
            libssh-dev \
        && docker-php-ext-install \
            bcmath \
            sockets \
        && pecl install amqp \
        && docker-php-ext-enable amqp

# Installing Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && composer --version

RUN apt-get -y install cron default-mysql-client
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql

WORKDIR /app

# Copy application files into the container
COPY . .

# Expose port 9000 for the PHP-FPM server
EXPOSE 9000

# The startup command to run PHP-FPM
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: When you say "it does not work", what URL are you connecting to, from where, and what happens?  One obvious thing I see is that you bind-mount a host directory over the containers' `/app` directories, which hides the code that's actually built into the image; it doesn't _seem_ like it will be a problem here, but this has caused some hard-to-understand issues in other Docker setups I've seen.